# CakePHP - Best way to persist application state?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have an app that tracks and displays various stats for a local athletic league.  One of my requirements is to be able to break down stats by game type, league id and location id.  The user picks a value for each of those 3 items and then goes off to view various stats with the 3 variables stored in a session.  This works fine, but my problem is that users can't link back to whatever stats they were viewing.  I know I can extend the life of the session, but I'd rather pass the state of those 3 variables around in the URL so I can have the ability to link back to any specific stats page with any or none of those 3 variables defined.

Query strings seem like an obvious way to do this, but I can't tell if there's any way for me to 'automatically' append the query string to all links generated in the app, or if I manually need to go through and add the querystring parameters wherever I generate a link or do a redirect.  That seems like the brute force approach and I feel like there must be a better way to do this sort of persistence that I'm missing.  Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a number of reasons (linking, SEO...etc), use a URL, not sessions/cookies.  And instead of IDs, use slugs instead:

> www.mysite.com/league/football/youth/newyork

I'm sure there are many different ways to keep the url vars consistent across the board, but the way I can think to do it would be the following:

- You can use Cake's route functionality to set each item to a variable and make nice looking URLs
- In your AppController's `beforeFilter()`, set the Session of each item (type, league, location)
- [Make a custom MyHtmlHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#using-and-configuring-helpers)
- in it, check if your Session for each contains data, and if it does, append to every link that needs it (could use only for specific controllers, actions...etc)

I hope there's a simpler way, but that's all I could think of offhand.

Comment: The combination of the session and the custom Helper actually sounds ideal!  Custom Helper never even occurred to me.  Thanks.